# MobX useObserver not working on destructed params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mobx, mobx-react

For example I have Store and App when I try to destruct Store's params useObserver not working React not re-render app when Store's title changes. But if I will not destruct params and will use directly in return like Store.title it will work. Why its working like this and how to fix it?

-- Store.js --

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx'
class Store{
  @observable title = "";

  @action handleTitleChange({ target: {value} }){
     this.title = value;
  }
}
```

-- App.js--  Not Working

```
import React from 'react'
import { useObserver } from 'mobx-react'
import Store from 'store'

export default () => {
  const { title, handleTitleChange } = Store
  return useObserver(() =>{
    <input value={title} onChange={handleTitleChange}>
  })
}
```

-- App2.js-- Working

```
import React from 'react'
import { useObserver } from 'mobx-react'
import Store from 'store'

export default () => {
  const { handleTitleChange } = Store
  return useObserver(() =>{
    <input value={Store.title} onChange={handleTitleChange}>
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation was explained in "Understanding reactivity" part of the docs https://mobx.js.org/understanding-reactivity.html

You are dereferencing value outside of `observer` decorator (`useObserver` if your case). You either need to do it like you did in the second example, or wrap whole component with `observer`, like that:

```
import React from 'react'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'
import Store from 'store'

export default observer(() => {
  const { title, handleTitleChange } = Store
  return <input value={title} onChange={handleTitleChange} />
})
```